# select from multiple table with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I had my query set up the other day as so

```
$query = "SELECT card_id,title,description,meta_description,seo_keywords,price 
FROM cards,card_cheapest order by card_id";
```

As you can see, I was selecting `card_id,title,description,meta_description,seo_keywords` from the table `cards`, and price was coming from `cheapest_card`. They both have the `card_id` in common (in both tables). However, I ran into a bit of an issue. When I run the query in navicat lite, I receive an error `"card_id is ambiguous"`. Was I doing something wrong?

Comment: did you want to join the tables ?

Comment: Error Says the 2 tables have the same column name, DB is not identifying which one to take, so you need to the alias for each table in the name and use that alias to refer the particular column to retrieve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When 2 or more tables have a column that is named the same, you have to qualify the table you want the column to be from.

i.e.:

```
$query = "SELECT cards.card_id,title,description,meta_description,seo_keywords,price
FROM cards,card_cheapest order by card_id";
```

Furthermore, do you really want to run the query this way, without a WHERE/JOIN-clause to define how to JOIN the two tables?

```
$query = "SELECT cards.card_id,title,description,meta_description,seo_keywords,price 
FROM cards,card_cheapest WHERE cards.card_id = card_cheapest.card_id 
ORDER BY card_id";
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have the same column name in two tables you're selecting from, you have to prefix the part in the `SELECT` with one of the table names (it doesn't matter which if it's the same data)

such as `SELECT cards.card_id, ...`

**EDIT:** However, cularis's answer is much more explanatory than mine, and take note about joining the two card_id columns if you want to get correct results.

Answer (score 0):

When you run queries that get information from multiple tables with shared field names you need to specify from which table you want to extract what field. You do this by specifying the table name before the field name.

In your case you have two options:

cards.card_id or card_cheapest.card_id.

Also I agree with @cularis, you are probably better of doing a join, but still you will need to specify which card_id you want to select: the one from cards or card_cheapest.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I still don't quite understand JOIN, which is why I didnt use it. But I appreciate the help!